# C# server sends UDP packets to a Java Client

Tags: c#, java, android, udp

im working on a project where i should transfer data from a c# server to an Java client (running on android device).
i need to use UDP protocol for a real time data and to maintain performance.
searching the web. didnt find any similar example and i really dont know where to start.

can you please suggest if this can be done ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done. That's one of the beautiful things about the Internet protocols: support for standard sockets is so widespread and common that disparate devices running vastly different CPU architectures and software environments can interoperate with nearly no trouble.

Please make sure that UDP is really the best tool for the job. Do you need reliable delivery? Do you need in-order delivery? How much packetloss can you tolerate? How much packet re-ordering can you tolerate? Will your application handle 540 byte packets as gracefully as it will handle 1500 byte packets? Does your application need to protect against [man in the middle attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack)? How?

TCP is an incredible protocol. Many attempts to use UDP "for speed" wind up re-implementing many of the things that TCP provides for you already -- but most re-implementations are not done nearly as well as the real thing. Please don't be so quick to dismiss TCP.

To get started, just about any network tutorial for Java and C# should include something like a chat or echo server, the network programming equivalent of "Hello World". And that'd be good enough for a *simple* environment. If you intend for your server to handle dozens of clients simultaneously, it'll be more work, and if you intend for your server to scale into the hundreds or thousands, it'll be a [different style of programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libevent) altogether.

Comment: Hey , thanks for your reply.
the point is that im going to use UDP to send image frames on realtime to the client, so i do need UDP to maintain performance as well as that i need somehow to be able to have ID's for frames recieved and display them in right order. so if i received image with ID 5 and displayed it and after that i got ID 3 , i will discard it . can you please point to a starting point on how to build such a UDP packet including ID's and length .

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reading this:

http://nickstips.wordpress.com/2010/09/03/c-creating-and-sending-udp-packets/

The client is irrelevant, it can be Java, C++, or any other language/platform. Doesn't matter.
The protocol is still the same.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Oracle Documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/index.html) as a starting point with UDPs, there you can find an example which i in java but as mentioned the idea of the [protocols](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) is to support a language independent communication.